# Using javascript to save a text entry to local storage

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am trying to use javascript to save a text entry using local storage with little success could anyone offer any advice please as i'm new to javascript. It is for a basic blog post site where the user submits text into a diary entry. I'm particularly unsure about how to get the textarea elements current value as shown in the code below and think that is where im going wrong.

```js
function addTextEntry(itemKey, initialText, isNewEntry) {
  // Create a textarea element to edit the entry
  var textElement = document.createElement("textarea");
  textElement.rows = 5;
  textElement.placeholder = "(new entry)";

  textElement.value = initialText;

  addSection(itemKey, textElement);

  // If this is a new entry (added by the user clicking a button)
  // move the focus to the textarea to encourage typing
  if (isNewEntry) {
    textElement.focus();
  }

  // Create an event listener to save the entry when it changes
  function saveEntry() {
    console.log("saveEntry called with variables in scope:", {
      itemKey,
      initialText,
      isNewEntry,
      textElement,
    });


    // Save text entry
    // ...get the textarea element's current value
    textElement = document.getElementById;
    // ...make a text item using the value
    textElement.value = initialText;
    //    (demonstrated elsewhere in this file)
    // ...store the item in local storage using the given key
    localStorage.setItem(itemKey);
  }

  // Connect the saveEntry evenFt listener to the textarea element 'change' event
  textElement.addEventListener("change", saveEntry);
  // (demonstrated elsewhere in this file)
}
```

Comment: the easiest way is to put your text in a json format and then stringify it to put it in the localstorage, but be careful the capacity is limited

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) wrong.

Try the following to get the current value of a `<textarea>`:

```js
function logTextareaValue () {
  const element = document.getElementById('myTextarea')
  const value = element.value
  console.log(value)
}
```

```html
<textarea id="myTextarea">Default text</textarea>
<button onClick="logTextareaValue()">Click to log textarea value to console</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

In you code, you are passing only one parameter `itemKey` to the `setItem()` method. You should also pass the value for that key as a second parameter.

```js
localStorage.setItem(itemKey, itemValue);
```